# Find whether the given string is in the list, even if the list has some characters only - Python

Tags: python, string

My code:

```
url = "testwork//SiteAssets//Test Workspace Notebook"
my_list = ["SiteAssets"]

if url in my_list:
  print('Yes having')
else:
  print('No')
```

I need to print **Yes having** because it has the keyword SiteAssets in my list. But else condition is working now.

Comment: here you are checking if `url` is in `my list`, instead check, `if any(item in url for item in my_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if any of the list items is in the url, not if the url is in the list. You can use `for else` for that

```
for l in my_list:
    if l in url:
        print('Yes having')
        break
else:
    print('No')
```

This will print "Yes" if any of the items in the list is in the url, and print "No" if the `if` condition was never `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks if whole `url` string is in your list. 
Instead do

```
for value in my_list:
  if(value in url):
    print("Yes")
  else:
    print("No")
```